# Automatic update of choices in a multi-select field

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

Using InfoPath 2013, I have a multi-select/MultiChoicetype field.  How does one set up the the multi-selection box get all valid possible choices dynamically so if a new choice is added for the field, it will appear in the list of choices in the form?